# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angular, ionic4

Alguien sabe acerca de este error, Me pasa cuando conecto mi proyecto de ionic 4 en el servidor 000wehost.com, de manera local me sirve con Xampp. pero al subirlo al host me da el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostProvider {
    server: string = "https://proyectoapptuestilo.000webhostapp.com/server_api/proses-api.php/"; // default
    //server: string = "http://localhost/Conexion/server_api/proses-api.php/"; // default
    // if you test in real device "http://localhost" change use the your IP

```
constructor(public http : Http) {

}

postData(body, file){
    let type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.server + file, JSON.stringify(body), options)
    .map(res => res.json());

}
```

}

Comment: Podrias aportar mas datos sobre tu problema empezando que has intentado?

Comment: intento hacer un registro de usuarios de mi App a la base de datos, como mencionaba de manera local me sirve pero al subirlo a host de la web no me sirve.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pudiste solucionarlo ?